# Pandas series - how to validate each item is categorical

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, dtype

I am importing data which **should** be categorical from an externally sourced csv file into a pandas dataframe.

The first thing I want to do is to validate that the values are valid for the categorical type.

My strategy is to create an instance of `CategoricalDtype` and then using `apply` to test each value.

**Question:** The only way I can figure out is to test each value is `in` `CategoricalDtype.categories.values` but is there a "better" way? are there any methods I can use to achieve the same? I'm new to `CategoricalDtype` and it doesnt feel like this is the best way to be testing the data value.

```
# example of what I'm doing
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
cat = CategoricalDtype(categories=["A", "B", "C"], ordered=False)

df['data_is_valid']=df['data_field'].apply(lambda x: x in cat.categories.values)
```

Comment: Why don't you simply check that the dtype of the column is `category`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need test if exist values from column `data_field` :

```
df['data_is_valid']=df['data_field'].isin(cat.categories)
```

If need test also `categorical_dtype`:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_categorical_dtype

df['data_is_valid']=df['data_field'].isin(cat.categories) & is_categorical_dtype(df['data_field'])
```

Difference is possible see in data sample:

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
from pandas.api.types import is_categorical_dtype
            
df = pd.DataFrame({ "data_field": ["A", "B", "C", "D", 'E']})

cat = CategoricalDtype(categories=["A", "B", "C"], ordered=False)

#categories match but not Categorical
df['data_is_valid1']=df['data_field'].isin(cat.categories) & is_categorical_dtype(df['data_field'])
#categories match not tested Categorical
df['data_is_valid2']=df['data_field'].isin(cat.categories)

cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=["A", "B", "C", 'D', 'E'], ordered=True)

#created Categorical column
df['data_field'] = df['data_field'].astype(cat_type)

#categoriesand Categorical match
df['data_is_valid3']=df['data_field'].isin(cat.categories) & is_categorical_dtype(df['data_field'])
#categories match not tested Categorical
df['data_is_valid4']=df['data_field'].isin(cat.categories)

print (df)
  data_field  data_is_valid1  data_is_valid2  data_is_valid3  data_is_valid4
0          A           False            True            True            True
1          B           False            True            True            True
2          C           False            True            True            True
3          D           False           False           False           False
4          E           False           False           False           False
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @jezrael - `df['data_is_valid']=df['data_field'].isin(cat.categories)` will suffice but thanks for the additional colour